# "Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to access a AWS SSM Parameter value and depending on that value I want to send response, but when I try to access it using "data.Parameter.Value" I am getting the below error.
What is the correct way to do it.

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:10:32)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:73:25)"
  ]
}
```

Code is below

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const ssm = new (require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm'))();
    var data = ssm.getParameter({
          Name: '/dev/cdn/test',
          WithDecryption: true
            }).promise();
        console.log(data.Parameter.Value);
    if (data.Parameter.Value == 'Down') {
        const redirectResponse = {
            status: '503',
            statusDescription: 'Service Unavailable',
            };
        console.log(JSON.srtingify(redirectResponse));
        callback(null, redirectResponse);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While a Promise object is "pending" (working), the result is undefined.

Please take a look at a more cleaner approach which AWS provides in its documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/classes/getparametercommand.html